# Acumatica - Get list of all Published Customization

Tags: acumatica

I want to check the published customization in my code, as Code is dependent of other customization.
(The customization that need to be checked is not having any feature associated with it, so can not check ISActive flag)

**How can I get list of all published projects at runtime??**
Acumatica version - 23 R1 onwards
On net If found following code

```
**SELECT c.* FROM dbo.CustProject c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.CustPublishProject WHERE ProjectID = c.ProjID)**
```

but there is no table available in DB named "CustPublishProject "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all published project with this code:

```
CstWebsiteStorage.PublishedProjectNames();
```

CstWebsiteStorage is in PX.Web.Customization.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, all the information regarding the published customizations is stored in the CustomizationPublishedInfo.xml file in the AppData folder.
So you can try reading the file and getting the information that you need.

[image]